# Cloning multiple copies of an Android app

Tags: android

I want to use multiple WhatsApp accounts on my mobile phone. I am aware of some apps like 2Accounts, Multiple Accounts, etc. But they allow clones only once and need a paid subscription for multiple clones. Is there any app for multiple cloning for free?

Separately I found an app named `super clone,` which does allow multiple WhatsApp but causes problems with sending pics, etc.

Comment: Given the first answer provided is specific to WhatsApp, would you like to make your question more specific to just apply to WhatsApp?  Another choice would be to generalize your question to make it less WhatsApp-centric.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Whatsapp is still linked to the same phone number unless you have dual sims.  Do you perhaps. have more than 2 sims on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

[WhatsApp Business](https://apkpure.com/whatsapp-business/com.whatsapp.w4b) enables using multiple numbers on a phone, in addition to using the regular WhatsApp. So you can install both on your phone without cloning. I have been using both for a while on Android.

Edit:
The answer was for if you have dual SIMs on a phone, or usually swap SIMs. In any case it enables multiple numbers.