# I need an app in Android that are able to let me clone applications that doesn't slow my phone when not in use

Tags: android, app

Several apps is fine.

The purpose of the app is as back up app for my e-wallet.

Say I put $2k on my crypto wallet. Say I lost the phone. I can just use the back up. So like one phone have a few backups.

So the extra apps will *rarely* be used.

Now I need an app to clone those wallet, whatsapp, telegrams app

There are many I know

[Cloning multiple copies of an Android app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83647/cloning-multiple-copies-of-an-android-app)

The catch is I've heard that things like parallel space will slow down my phone.

Is this true? How can an app slow down a phone when the app is not even in use? I must be missing something.

I need apps that *doesn't* slow down my phone when *not* in use.

Minimum ads is also fine, too.

So something like clone apps in oppo or dual apps in xiaomi.

Comment: You are asking "Is this true?". Looks like you should do some investigation before asking for a piece of software. Probably you haven't understood your problem in first place?